# Export highchart for print preview

Tags: printing, highcharts, export, preview

I have to create a print preview page where I have to show some information and a highchart of the original page. Is there a way to export the highchart graph from one page to another?

Answer (score 0):

There are probably many ways to accomplish this.

What language are you working in?

I would try it this way:

- set the chart options in an external js file
- include that js file in both the original page, and the 'preview' page
- I assume the user will click on a link or button to open the preview page...?
- send the data via POST to the new page, and instantiate the chart on the new page on page load

You could also look into using the Export package to

- on link/button click, export the chart as an image, to the server

  - pass the url of the saved image to the new page, and load the image there

I have not worked with exporting to the server, and wouldn't bother with the set up for this when you can just pass the data and build the chart on the new page, but it's an option.